terraform plan -detailed-exitcode is returning 0 when we have changes
I have one change in my test infra when I am running terrafrom plan on travis
with command

terraform plan -detailed-exitcode

I am getting follwoing output
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution

plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:

  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # ip_collection.planner_test1 will be created

  + resource "ip_collection" "planner_test1" {

      + description = "Planner_test1"

      + environment = "att"

      + id          = (known after apply)

      + ips         = [

          + "1.2.3.4",


        ]

      + name        = "Planner_test1"

    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

on capturing return code with:
local plan_output=$(terraform plan -no-color -detailed-exitcode 2>&1) && plan_rc=0 || plan_rc=$?
I am getting 0 instead of 2
trying to use it in logic to print git comment in PR:
function git_comment() {
    local command_output="${1}"
    local output_code="${2}"

    message=$(echo "${command_output}" | grep -E 'No changes.|Plan: ([0-9\(\)]+\sto\sadd,\s[0-9\(\)]+\sto\schange,\s[0-9\(\)]+\sto\sdestroy.)|Error:')

    if [ "${output_code}" -eq 0 ]; then
        print_info "${message}"
        payload=$(build_git_comment "No changes" ":large_blue_circle:" "${message}")
    elif [ "${output_code}" -eq 2 ]; then
        print_success "${message}"
        payload=$(build_git_comment "Success" ":green_circle:" "${message}" "${command_output}")
    else
        print_fail "${message}"
        payload=$(build_git_comment "Failed" ":red_circle:" "${message}" "${command_output}")
    fi
    print_info "********** ADDING DETAILED PLAN TO PR **********"
    add_git_comment "${payload}"
}

I tried diffrent Terraform versions no joy

Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do i.e. why do you need to get the exit code of terraform plan?

I am using it to add git comment using return code to make conditions

doesn't the return code in this case refer to the execution of terraform plan? And since it executes successfully, the return code is "0"
